# Counting consecutive repeats in a string and returning a value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Asked my friend to give me an assignment for me to practice. It is:

> If a user enters a string `"AAABNNNNNNDJSSSJENDDKEW"` the program will return 
>   `"3AB6NDJ2SJEN2DKEW"` and vice versa.

This what I tried so far:

```
from collections import Counter
list_user_input =[]
list_converted_output=[]
current_char = 0 #specifies the char it is reading
next_char = 1
cycle = 0 # counts number of loops
char_repeat = 1
prev_char=""
count = 1
user_input = input("Enter your string: ")
user_input_strip = user_input.strip()
user_input_striped_replace = user_input_strip.replace(" ", "").lower()
list_user_input.append(user_input_striped_replace[0:len(user_input_striped_replace)])
print(list_user_input)
print(user_input_striped_replace)
```

I have "cleaned" the code so it removes white spaces and keeps it in low cap

Here is where I am stuck - the logics. I was thinking to go the through the string one index at a time and compare the next on to the other. Is this the wright way to go about it? And I'm not even sure about the loop construction.

```
#counter = Counter(list_user_input)
#print(counter)


#while cycle <= len(user_input_striped_replace):
for letter in user_input_striped_replace:
    cycle+=1
    print("index nr {}, letter: ".format(current_char)+letter +" and cycle : " + str(cycle))
    current_char+=1

    if letter[0:1] == letter[1:2]:
        print("match")


    print("index nr {}, letter: ".format(current_char)+letter +" and cycle : " + str(cycle))
    current_char+=1
```

Comment: How will getting the answer here help you practice?

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is a good choice for such task but about the rest you can use `sorted` to sort the items of `Counter` then use a list comprehension to create the desire list then concatenate with `join` :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter(s)
>>> sor=sorted(c.items(),key=lambda x:s.index(x[0]))
>>> ''.join([i if j==1 else '{}{}'.format(j,i) for i,j in sor])
'3AB7N3D2J3S2EKW'
```

Comment: That doesn't handle separate runs of the same letter correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Have a look at those.

Spoiler:

```
import re
def encode(s):
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda m: str(len(m.group(0)))+m.group(1), s)
def decode(e):
    return re.sub('(\d+)(.)', lambda m: int(m.group(1))*m.group(2), e)

s = "AAABNNNNNNDJSSSJENDDKEW"
e = encode(s)
print(e, decode(e) == s)
```

Prints:

```
3AB6NDJ3SJEN2DKEW True
```

Your *"and vice versa"* sentence sounds like the program needs to detect itself whether to encode or to decode, so here's that (proof of correctness left as an exercise :-)

```
def switch(s):
    e = re.sub(r'(\D)\1+', lambda m: str(len(m.group(0)))+m.group(1), s)
    d = re.sub('(\d+)(.)', lambda m: int(m.group(1))*m.group(2), s)
    return e if e != s else d
```

Comment: Thank you both !
Stefan the 1+ part in encode, what does that do ?

Comment: `\D` means non-digit. The parentheses capture it so I can refer to it with `\1`. The `+` says "one or more". Overall, here, this says *"a letter that is repreated at least once"*.